# Does it make sense to learn Ada for general programming?

Tags: ada

I have read that Ada is rock-solid and very reliable, and that it has lots of programming resources. Does it make sense to learn and use Ada for general programming? (i.e. not for scientific or engineering projects)

Comment: Questions like `Should I learn <language X>?` are considered off topic.

Comment: Ask in comp.lang.ada or reddit.com/r/ada.

Comment: I edited the question, changing "generic" to "general", since "generic" has a specific meaning in Ada.

Comment: See also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2662397/230513).

Comment: @KeithThompson - Also Generics in Ada is the best i have come across for generics/templating.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does make sense to learn and use Ada for programming in general, but (as is often the case) it depends a lot on what exactly you are interested in (the only thing I'm sure of is that Ada is rather bad choice for doing quick and dirty hacks (not that it cannot be done)).